# Can I ask about the cursing?

Tags: discussion, scope

I want to ask about swearing language in Ukrainian. I've heard that it's overflown with Russian cusses and wanted to ask if there's such a thing  as a Ukrainian or, perhaps, West Ukrainian cursing at all?

Comment: Personally I can recall "холєра" from Ukrainian curses (basically it's a name of a disease - cholera). However there may be lots of other words I'm not aware of.

Comment: My question is if i can ask it on the main site, not on meta.

Comment: @P.Vovk  Even though your first question was shut down I have a feeling that the main site would benefit from such questions. BTW, have you checked out "Українська мова без табу. Словник нецензурної лексики та її відповідників. Леся Ставицька"?

Comment: @s0nata I think the site benefits from me being on it in general hhh but I feel like they'll ban me soon, everyone is aggressive (IT guys, I suppose).

I've heard about the book, but I didn't really check it out.
I've found it scanned on http://padaread.com, is it OK, have they granted free access to it at Harvard?

Answer (score 10):

I think you can, however try to avoid "too broad" questions (like "give me the full list of curses" etc.)

Many linguists think that expelling curses from the dictionaries during Soviet times was wrong, because it is a part of a language.

For example, during 1903-1909 3rd edition of Dahl dictionary was released which contained many swear words added by the editor, professional linguist Иван (Ян) Александрович Бодуэн де Куртенэ (see [here](http://arzamas.academy/materials/1100)). This edition of the dictionary was never printed again during Soviet times.

> «Лексикограф не имеет права урезывать и кастрировать „живой язык“. Раз известные слова существуют в умах громадного большинства народа и беспрестанно выливаются наружу, лексикограф обязан занести их в словарь, хотя бы против этого восставали и притворно негодовали все лицемеры и тартюфы, являющиеся обыкновенно большими любителями сальностей по секрету…»

Comment: Thanks, i'll wait for one more person to approve and then ask it on the main page

Comment: I agree with you, @Artemix. As long as it is specific and about the Ukrainian  language, it should be fine.

Comment: @s0nata very well, i'll think of the articulation and post it.
Thanks to both of you, guys.

Comment: In addition to this answer, one doesn't need to mask the swear words with asterisks or what. Provided that we discuss the linguistic aspects of the language, not blame on someone. :)

Comment: @bytebuster I've asked a question about it, but it was "too broad". I think it was you who said it's too broad and suggested to close it.
I don't know what exactly to ask, even though I think it's a very interesting topic.

Comment: @P.Vovk, it was too broad because it asked for an open-ended list. Everyone would answer you a *subset* of such list. It has nothing to do about masking the swear words with asterisks.

Comment: @bytebuster I know, I know, everyone is way too logical here.

Comment: @P.Vovk maybe you can ask for a resource on this topic? If you find something non-clear there you then can ask again here for the more details.

Comment: @Artemix Sonata has given me a hint: http://padaread.com/?book=54260&pg=9, so I'll maybe do what you're saying me to do.

It would be silly though, to ask about each separate word, as it is silly to ask about all of them in general.

Comment: @P.Vovk Very fundamental book. However the site is not recommended to visit without adblock of some kind. My tablet was bombed with suggestions to install .apk files or to "improve performance" on each new page.